# i am having problem in my vsCode like when i write .container its is not giving me any suggestion for making a class conainer with div element

Tags: visual-studio-code, autocomplete, autosuggest

What should i do for that i, think there must be any option that i have to turn it, please help me to get out of this....[Here you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxi5E.png)

Please Help me to resolve this problem

in my laptop when i installed vs code it works perfectly, but when i installed vscode in my desktop it is not giving me any suggestion to auto complete the tag

like when i write .container then it not giving any suggestion that i can click on it and it will change .container to

Comment: because it is a JavaScript file, try it in an HTML file, you can enable Emmet in JS files, see VSC emmet doc

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your setting to get this.
Go to setting (Ctrl + , ) search for "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab" then select the checkbox.
Now you when you type .container and hit Tab button and you get the results.

You can follow this link for more details: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/emmet#_using-tab-for-emmet-expansions

Answer (score 1):

I also had similar issue and solved using following steps.

1. Need to change the settings first

for that press `Ctrl` + `,` in your keyboard [image: Get Settings Option]

Then you will get settings window like this image.

2. Search `emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab` as shown in image [image: Search Option]
3. Then enable by adding tick there [image: How to enable]

Go to vs code and try it out. ( Plz make sure to press Tab after typing like .example-class-name)

Answer (score 0):

Go to VS Code setting type emmet in search
Locate the include language section. Click Add item to enter
item: javascript value: javascriptreact